# Replacing more than one substring value with pandas str.replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm looking for a way to simplify my code:

```
# Dataset
categorical_data = pd.Series(["dog", "lion", "cat", "crustacean", "dog", "insect", "insect", "cat", "crustacean"])
```

What I wanna do is to replace dogs, lions & cats with "animal". I can do them by writing this:

```
categorical_data = categorical_data.str.replace("dog", "animal")
categorical_data = categorical_data.str.replace("cat", "animal")
categorical_data = categorical_data.str.replace("lion", "animal")
```

Is there a way for the `str.replace()` function to accept a list of strings instead of just one?

Example:

```
categorical_data = categorical_data.str.replace([dog, lion, cat], "animal")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For replace by list is possible use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
categorical_data = categorical_data.replace(['dog', 'lion', 'cat'], "animal")    
print (categorical_data)
0        animal
1        animal
2        animal
3    crustacean
4        animal
5        insect
6        insect
7        animal
8    crustacean
dtype: object
```

Difference between answers is with subtrings replacement:

```
categorical_data = pd.Series(["dog gorilla", "lion", "cat", "crustacean"])

print (categorical_data.replace(['dog', 'lion', 'cat'], "animal"))
0    dog gorilla
1         animal
2         animal
3     crustacean
dtype: object

print (categorical_data.str.replace(r'(dog|cat|lion)', 'animal', regex=True))
0    animal gorilla
1            animal
2            animal
3        crustacean
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use a regex with `str.replace`, separating the strings to match with `|` which will be replacing *any* match among the specified strings:

```
categorical_data.str.replace(r'(dog|cat|lion)', 'animal', regex=True)

0        animal
1        animal
2        animal
3    crustacean
4        animal
5        insect
6        insect
7        animal
8    crustacean
dtype: object
```